# Use service into View AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have issue with angularJS Service.

I have simple service:

```
angular.module('mainApp.services', []).factory('AuthService',
function ($http) {
    //var currentUser = null;
    //var authorized = false;

    //AutoLogin for testing
    var currentUser={email: "example@example.com", id: "15"};
    var authorized=true;

    // initial state says we haven't logged in or out yet...
    // this tells us we are in public browsing
    var initialState = false;

    return {
        initialState:function () {
            return initialState;
        },
        login:function (userData) {
            //Call API Login
            currentUser = userData;
            authorized = true;
            initialState = false;
        },
        logout:function () {
            currentUser = null;
            authorized = false;
        },
        isLoggedIn:function () {
            return authorized;
        },
        currentUser:function () {
            return currentUser;
        },
        authorized:function () {
            return authorized;
        }
    };
});
```

then I have a simple Controller

```
.controller('NavbarTopCtrl', ['$scope','$modal','AuthService',function($scope,$modal,authService) {
    $scope.authService=authService;  //IS good practice?
    console.log($scope);
}])
```

I can't use my service into View. I made simple trick and works fine.

```
$scope.authService=authService
```

**But how to call Service without this in my View (HTML file)?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using services inside the views is generally a bad practice.
The view should contain only a presentation logic. 
In your example instead of passing the whole service to the view you could try to pass only a user object. For example `$scope.currentUser = authService.currentUser()`.

Comment: Look here to login Service. It works fine. https://github.com/robertjchristian/angular-enterprise-seed

Comment: What about when you have a set of functions you want callable from the view via something like `ng-click`? It is quite tedious to wrap every single function you want exposed to the view inside a caller function inside the controller. Thoughts?

Comment: myApp.configure(function($rootScope) { $rootScope.foo = function() { console.log("call me from everywhere ;)") });

Comment: Is `$scope.currentUser` bound to changes in `authService.currentUser()` ?