# Using service function in controller's ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set visibility of an element based on my service's function.
Is there a way to do that without duplicating the function within the controller again?

Service:

```
angular
.module('app')
.service('userService', userService);

userService.$inject = ['$window', '$rootScope', '$uibModalStack', '$state'];

function userService($window, $rootScope, $uibModalStack, $state) {

    var service = this;
    service.user = {};

    service.returnTrue= function() {
        return true;
    };

};
```

Controller's HTML:

```
<div>
   <p ng-if="userService.returnTrue()">Display if service's function returns true</p>
</div>
```

I want to avoid duplicating the function in my controller like this

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('mainController', mainController);

mainController.$inject = ['userService'];

function mainController(userService) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.returnTrue = function() {
        return userService.isInRole() 
    };
}
```

Here's a snippet of what I'm avoiding

```js
angular.module('app',[])

.service('userService', function(){
   var service = this;
   
   service.returnTrue = function() {
       return true;
   }
})

.controller('mainCtrl', function(userService){
  var vm = this;
  vm.disableSave = true
  
  vm.returnTrue = function() { 
     return userService.returnTrue()
  };
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
 <body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
  <p ng-if="vm.returnTrue()">Display if value returned is true</p>
</div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use service into View Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377202/use-service-into-view-angular-js)

Comment: The proposed duplicate is not a good answer to the question. It does not give a good example of a template. The accepted answer claims that embedding functions in template is bad practice, but does not explain why. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/20726588).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `service` to `vm` and then accessing the same in your template.

i.e.

You can update your controller as

```
function mainController(userService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.userService = userService;
}
```

And your html as

```
<div>
   <p ng-if="vm.userService.returnTrue()">Display if service's function returns true</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this not duplicating the userService though?

Comment: It is not duplicating, it is simply referencing to the same object. Also, there is no direct way of accessing service in template.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk it's fine because services are singletons. Only one instance is created, but then can be referenced elsewhere many times